# HTML cache manifest prevents browser from loading ressources

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I have got a HTML manifest with the lines:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
images/foo.png
```

Also, the page includes e.g. jQuery and many other ressources. All of them are not loaded, except the ones named in the manifest (here: `images/foo.png`). How can i tell the browser to load all files but the ones explicitly defined in the manifest?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281827/html5-cache-manifest-fallback-section-network see the NETWORK piece

Comment: @RobotWoods thanks :) If you'd put this into an answer, i can accept it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML5 Cache Manifest: Fallback section & Network *](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281827/html5-cache-manifest-fallback-section-network)

see the NETWORK piece, which prevents caching (also helpful in managing dynamic pages like PHP, etc)